# Split linked list c++

Tags: c++, split, linked-list

For this function, the return value type should be `Forward_list`, but I assign the list with node value type, so what's the alternative so that `my_list.head_` returns a `Forward_list`?

```
template <typename T>
Forward_list<T> Forward_list<T>::split()
{
    Forward_list<T> my_list;
    my_list.head_;
    my_list.size_;
    Node* tmp = head_;
    Node* tmp2 = head_;
    if(my_list.empty())
    {
        return *this;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;

    while (my_list.empty() == false)
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        if (tmp == nullptr) break;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp2 = tmp2->next;
    }
    tmp2= tmp2->next;
    my_list.head_ = tmp2;
    tmp2->next = nullptr;
    return my_list.head_;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `my_list.head_; my_list.size_;` are no-ops. And `my_list.empty()` will always be true, since you are not adding any nodes to `my_list`. And `return my_list.head_;` should be `return my_list;` to fix the error message. But worse of all, you are pointing `my_list.head_` to nodes that belong to `this`, so when `my_list` is destroyed on `return`, its destructor will destroy nodes it doesn't own. You must `new` a copied set of the nodes to `return` to the caller.

Comment: For that matter, why are you going to all of the trouble of looping through nodes just to set `my_list` to hold only 1 node prior to `return`? Your code is very confusing, what exactly are you trying to "split" out? What is the goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Same user and same problem as can be seen here:

[Split linked list into half in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965078/split-linked-list-into-half-in-c/71983632#71983632)

Mods should act more reasonable.

Same answer:

You did not show your code. That is a pity. So, I needed to stub it.

You have 3 main errors.

- Checking for the empty list is wrong. You are checking the just newly create my_list. This will of course always be empty.
- The traversing of the list is wrong
- The size calculation is wrong.

Please see the corrected code below:

```
template <typename T>
struct Forward_list {
    struct Node {
        T data{};
        Node* next{};
    };
    Node* head_{};
    unsigned int size_{};

    Forward_list<T> split();

    void push_back(const T& t);
    bool empty() const { return size_ == 0; }
};

template <typename T>
void Forward_list<T>::push_back(const T& t) {

    Node* data = new Node{ t,nullptr };

    if (head_ == nullptr)
        head_ = data;
    else {

        Node* tmp{ head_ };
        while (tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = data;
    }
    ++size_;

}

template <typename T>
Forward_list<T> Forward_list<T>::split()
{
    Forward_list<T> my_list;
    Node* tmp = head_;
    Node* tmp2 = head_;

    if (/*my_list.*/empty() == true)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    while (tmp->next != nullptr)
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        if (tmp->next == nullptr) break;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp2 = tmp2->next;
    }
    my_list.head_ = tmp2->next;
    tmp2->next = nullptr;
    my_list.size_ = size_/2; 
    size_ = size_ - my_list.size_;
    return my_list;
}
int main() {
    Forward_list<int> fw;
    for (int i{}; i < 3; ++i)
        fw.push_back(i);

    Forward_list<int> fw2 = fw.split(); 

}
```

---

Checksum:

xXrZx\rZtWR&vf=d"^KgjwCicpXQ"\z87\lm=PbYLi,b;u4T?6.0%RU33!9kGJZ29#`FOTrX$m+9l$Qsxi\7jRbJ'@e$I;V#i?%VXs/6n^3.Er:s#VAaqP:&NJS&HJMx3lGDtR84DQ0sqnb%V5&FOfK^,,cB*24mp?Sp5saOQ%rT;peTkW5:XVmSE*MZ8gx,of6p^grL#!hn:wY0E\l7B5brK0c7:Xpwf?UP'd'2Vo3aX2IJd,Dr^rC!u2?=x$OQ@zPkG'N'gDW3a@^b*x6tY8.;@X^L*&7Y7ySc8hRleorzry6o/o'lV5"@'*gKuwLVP`:^9THuC23M7t1!$oWn2Vy,:P;b@faTPfoE",#x'j,rT"iX=phBEQ.c!7$PcMZXB$qeIwY*Kui$`7skOdKSaNA`r*\UqZ%0aOI\MwF.8co4bCE'=Wzm5o2V^njo"P1Tb'?!%e^*wF@9Pf*sYl"iXX#`k78d'I3`?oCM6&A+Kwao2^`M5YU8Y24"JT*g0lr`!QDvIXXnYB!Nz$VW\EwuL'Z^n%R+C3MEZwh%#7G'mLqjD/V8?wIa,Nvh*@fJ:eYi0EmhnboEb@;$!T&xGF13jL:FsH@!VEqt%?Dz?!GXl2H/I\Ol%8ESv:pQwel7\DA,\Yrf2KrA"`q5s$i/!Iu&O!z3KH`6^K@QOG9'2XIxA*7&iyx*d2HjB!"6a%`=n@ykgK@VhyMk?M^v".S`mwpZ7ErWitq3bl%bYuxnY=2my%Y+E97&ch;`u=CFaqrqQ*k1tPLsD?Zo?F,I27bp9Q/FsO'GXVc,9`"F87,0ql$%NPB@jPw+vBIxwSbCQGN,PerVF*8VpKTO'LJm`KtS'w^Sm69Ozqb87XBNzN`k522l`5Ha'=:*0H?G:2bUX8Gr%\PhR"H2lE\0g6%Z$l\b2/LpP:D`UaqzHB`+;pg\%pU3Moi%bO&`alQ@FImfWxSR;X^Vt`!yA1+389dikl,fYdElr6W;dObtIz$jsGx$V^f8zJ'hBYZnO+Ou?ShEJZVHGq